# Unable to access MongoCollection Class from MongoDB.Driver for C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to access the [Save()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Save.htm) method detailed in the driver documentation, but there seems to be no definition at all of the method when I call the function from an `IMongoCollection`, and the class `MongoCollection` is not found or recognized by the IDE.

The reason I am trying to call `Save()` instead of `Update()`, is that I want it to be by `_id`, I am trying to implement a generic `IMongoRepository()` that would just update a document within a collection without needing any extra information.

[image: error when trying to call Save()]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Save` (as well as MongoCollection class itself) is deprecated method in the Legacy driver, the current driver doesn't have this functionality, see [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1.htm)

Comment: the whole legacy driver is considered depricated

Comment: 2.13.1 consist of 2 parts: `MongoDB.Driver` and `MongoDB.Driver.Legacy` (and some other parts like GridFS). The Legacy part will be removed in the next major release

Comment: the nuget that contains MongoCollection is this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/ (aka Legacy)